# camera sensors - smartphones

Tags: camera, sensors, smartphone

How do camera sensors work on smartphones. ( I am not looking for the APIs but the technical details).

Is it the CCD image sensor that is used or the CMOS sensors? I am looking for both iOS and android devices. Any help/resources appreciated